# Looking to rename a batch of cab files to lowercase as well as adding their SHA1 Hash

Tags: batch

I need a batch script to rename all the files in a folder their lowercase equivalent, with their SHA1 hash added at the end after an underscore.

Example:

I have a file called: "Windows8.1-KB2862152-x86.cab"
it's hash is "bc44b5c4daca0fb2a7b596bafb3d751231983c0e"
so I need it renamed to:
windows8.1-kb2862152-x86_bc44b5c4daca0fb2a7b596bafb3d751231983c0e.cab
where the W is now lowercase and the KB are also lowercase.

I have a MASSIVE amount of these files that I need in this format.

I should also mention that I have the SHA1 tool from IBM Endpoint Manager(sha1.exe)
usage is as follows:

```
sha1 [-r|-s|-m|-b] <filename> [-c]

-r: Calculate Size/Sha1 and print out a prefetch style statement for 6.0+ style downloads (use this normally).
-s: Sha1 only.
-m: Sha1 in MIME format (hex-encoded and base-64).
-b: Calculate Size/sha1 and print out a prefetch block statment for 7.2+ style downloads.
-c: Puts the result string into you paste buffer so you don't need to copy/paste out of the command window.
```

I have the following script which I found on this site, but get "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

```
@ECHO OFF
SET FULLNAME=%~f1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('sha1.exe -s %FULLNAME%') do SET hash=%%a
ren %FULLNAME% %FULLNAME%_%hash%
```

apparently it's called by: for %A IN (C:\PathToFolder*) DO C:\SomeFolder\hasher.bat "%A"
however this also won't help with the lowercase renaming, and I think it would lose the file extension.

Comment: Welcome to SU! We are not a script writing service. If you have a script you're working on we can help, but you'll need to supply what you've got already, what you've tried, and where exactly you're getting stuck implementing the batch script you want.

Comment: sorry about that, I updated the post. I actually messed around with this but couldn't get it working, I was just looking for some insights :)

Answer (score 0):

Your script should work fine if you pass the file name as an argument. For example, save it as hash.bat and run `hash.bat Windows8.1-KB2862152-x86.cab` from the command line.

That script will rename the file to **Windows8.1-KB2862152-x86.cab_bc44b5c4daca0fb2a7b596bafb3d751231983c0e**

If I understand correctly, you want the **.cab** extension at the end and you want the file name to be all lower case.

To fix the .cab part, use substitution. Change the last line in your script from:

```
ren %FULLNAME% %FULLNAME%_%hash%
```

to

```
ren %FULLNAME% %FULLNAME:.cab=%_%hash%.cab
```

Now, add another line to rename all files to lower case. dir /l lists output in lower case, so list all files and rename them according to output:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /l /b /s /a-d') do ren "%%a" "%%a"
```

So, your script should be:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET FULLNAME=%~f1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('sha1.exe -s %FULLNAME%') do SET hash=%%a
ren %FULLNAME% %FULLNAME:.cab=%_%hash%.cab
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /l /b /s /a-d') do ren "%%a" "%%a"
```

You will need to modify the script for your working directory or run the script from the same directory where you store your .cab files.